# Marketing Cloud Journey not triggering when resyncing contacts from Salesforce (after Contact Deletion)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, contact-deletion

**Background:**
Due to the contractual contact limit, contacts in Marketing Cloud are being deleted by the "Contact Deletion by Contact Key" API from Salesforce. A checkbox field on the contact object is being used to flag contacts that are not eligible to be synced to Marketing Cloud. This field is used as a filter on the Contact data sources (**Sync flag = True**)

The use case is whenever the flag is updated to True on a contact record, it will get synced to Marketing Cloud (Polling frequency set to 15 mins) else an Apex Batch job will delete the contact from MC (Flag = False).

**Problem description:**
The issue we are having is the Journey Builder (Email) is not firing if the contact gets synced the second time:

1. A contact "John" is created with Flag = True in Salesforce. John is synced immediately to Marketing Cloud and the "Welcome Email" journey builder works fine. **Question A**: How is the contact synced immediately when the polling frequency is set to 15 mins? Only happens for new contacts in SF
2. After one week, John is no longer eligible to be in Marketing Cloud. The flag is updated to False and John record is deleted from MC using an API call from Salesforce.
3. The second week, John is again eligible to be on Marketing Cloud and there is Journey builder when case record is created for email notification. John opens a case in Salesforce and the Sync flag is updated to True. Now, the John record is synced to Marketing Cloud after 15 mins. **Question B:** Although the Entry Criteria of the "New Case" Journey Builder are met, it is not being triggered. Why? Is there a delay that the Journey Builder does not get triggered.

"New Case" Journey Builder:

1. Type: Event using data Extension
2. Action: Updated
3. Object: Contact

**Question C**: How is the Journey builder gets triggered? Is it based on the data extension, which means if a record is not in the data extension, it will not get triggered?